# Box2d sensors don't detect contacts

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, contacts

**My problem:**

Weapon body stoped detecting contacts when i make it's fixture sensor.

**ContactListener code:**

```
void preSolve(contact: Contact, oldManifold:Manifold){

        switch (fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits | fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits) {
            case Game.WEAPON_BIT | Game.ENEMY_BIT: bodyDeleteList.add(contact.getFixtureA().getBody());
            System.out.println("Contact!");  // this never prints
            break;
        }
}
```

When i make body fixture regular(commenting fixtureDef.setFixtute(true)) everything becomes great and contacts occur and detecting.

**Documentation says:**

> /** A sensor shape collects contact information but never generates a
>   collision response. */

But it doesn't. So maybe i forgot something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by adding this code to `beginContact(..)` method.

**It's strange, but sensors only collect contact information in `beginContact(..)` method**.

```
void beginContact(contact: Contact){

     switch (fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits | fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits) {
            case Game.WEAPON_BIT | Game.ENEMY_BIT: bodyDeleteList.add(contact.getFixtureA().getBody());
            System.out.println("Contact!");  // this prints
            break;
     }
}
```